# Https doesn't load some resources

Tags: https, spring-security, internet-explorer-7

I have problem using https for the website I'm working on. I'm using spring Security.
Everything work fine in http but when I use https one of my css file is not loaded, and some js file too.
My css file a liked like this
`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="common/css/gestion_donnees_ref.css>`

so this is my request

`GET /triWebapp/common/css/donnees_ref.css HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.24.192.169:444
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0
Accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Accept-Language: fr,fr-fr;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: https://10.24.192.169:444/triWebapp/gestionDonneesReference
Cookie: JSESSIONID=eYvbCpcb2NNY4zvWtah3Rfhp
Connection: keep-alive`

and the response

`HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Mon, 24 Nov 2014 15:43:08 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: http://tipi.hd.prod.me.edf.fr/triWebapp/common/css/donnees_ref.css
Content-Length: 250
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1`

it seems that the conent type is wrong here but I don't know why.

Comment: What is the status code of your failed http requests?

Comment: The status of the request is Aborted

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you remove Spring Security? What happens if you request the aborted resources directly? Can you supply the complete HTTP request/response for the aborted resources?

Comment: Yes i have the same problem when i remove spring security. I appears that some resources are loaded using http and not https